# Profiling hadoop job with yourkit

Tags: java, hadoop, utf-8, profiling, yourkit

I am following this tutorial http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster

I want to see which method or java process that use all the CPU as wordCount mapper going through the corpus by using yourkit.  As I understand that Hadoop type "Text" is in utf-8 and Java String is in utf-16. I am trying to see that wordCount mapper does most the work in converting from utf-8 to utf-16.

However, yourkit doesn't show much details about this process.  It only shows CPU time as follow:
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(String[])  ~ 96% and org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$ResponseProcessor.run() ~ 4%

I am not very familiar with yourkit.  Could someone please point out how should I approach this?